# postgres performance is very slow with django

Tags: django, postgresql

I made a very small web-app in django with sqllite3 and then I just connected the same app to postgres db in which I reccreated the tables using makemigrations and then now when I am using even the admin page, with just one superuser - admin - its very very slow.
I tried postgresql.conf file to set the parameters - seq_page_cost = 1.0 and random_page_cost = 1.0 and restarted postgres.sql from services, but to no avail.
is there anything I need to do apart from this ?? please let me know.

Comment: What's the latency between the postgres server and your Django server?

Comment: I have it in my laptop with django and Postgres both on my laptop and it used to be a fraction of seconds when I was using it with SQLite3 whereas now with Postgres with just one user admin, the local host:8001/admin is taking more than 40 secs and even start of django server takes time which was instant with SQLite

Comment: That's pretty unusual. What does [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) say about how long each SQL query takes?

Comment: Can you please once suggest how to use the django-debug-toolbar - haven’t used it - as I saw from the above link, I can pip install django debug toolbar and if then you can tell me next steps to monitor where is the hang in this… postgres

Comment: OS and version? What does Postgres log show when you connect/issue query?  What is the connection parameters you are using to connect? Add answers as update to your question. My suspicion is that it is a network issue related to the connection making contact with the server.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, the os is Windows 10 the connection parameters in the settings.py are below 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
  'NAME': 'roomreservation',
  'USER' : 'kkk',
  'PASSWORD' : 'kkkpwd123',
  'HOST' : 'localhost',
  'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}
I only hit 127.0.0.1:8000/admin through browser and then django internally renders the admin ui and this is a default ui but before this rendering as well, if you see the boot of django server which is by command "django r" is like 40 secs and more... it starts though

Comment: django version 3.2.9 and I believe I am using python 3

Comment: I saw at the django console - it gives this error [27/Nov/2021 09:09:40,962] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50988) but after that too it does show up the UI - after some lag though.